# jQuery Add Class on Click but only allowed once.

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I have so far:
[image]

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

So this is working, it is adding the class but I want only one item to be active at all times.  So when I click on an item, and it turns active, the next item I click on should be the new active one, and remove the class on the previous one.

Does that make sense?  How can I do something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to first remove the `active` class from your `thumb_wrapper` elements. Try this:

```
$(".thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
    $(".thumb_wrapper").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Cache your wrapper and call a **[`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)** on it first:

```
var $wrapper = $(".thumb_wrapper");

$wrapper.click(function() {
    $wrapper.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".thumb_wrapper").on('click', function() {
    $(".thumb_wrapper").removeClass('active').find(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".thumb_wrapper").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().children().each(function() { 
             $(this).removeClass("active");
         });
         $(this).addClass("active");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.what').click(function(){
        $('.what').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');       
   });       
});
```

I assume something like this?